# Question about solution

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-webflow

I have two flows configured in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="mytService.createUserForm()" result="flowScope.userForm" />
    </on-start>

    <view-state id="register" view="account/registerForm" model="userForm">     
        <on-render>
            <set name="requestScope.countryList" value="mytService.getCountryList()" />
        </on-render>
        <transition on="submitRegistration" to="addAccount" bind="true" validate="true" />
        <transition on="cancelRegistration" to="cancelRegistration"
            bind="false" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="accountAdded" view="account/registeringForm">
        <transition on="sendOnceAgain" to="registering">
            <evaluate expression="myService.sendOnceAgain()"></evaluate>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="addAccount">
        <evaluate expression="myService.addAccount(userForm)" />
        <transition to="accountAdded" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="cancelRegistration" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/home.do" />

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on="changeLang">

        </transition>
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <input name="hash" required="true"/>

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="myService.createUserForm()" result="flowScope.userForm" />
    </on-start>

    <action-state id="decideAction">
        <set name="flowScope.goTo" value ="mytService.verifyHash(hash)" />
        <transition to="${goTo}"></transition> 
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="correctVerify" view="account/registeredForm" model="userForm">
        <transition on="addPhoneNumber" to="correctVerify">
            <evaluate expression="myService.addPhoneNumber(userForm)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="deletePhoneNumber" to="correctVerify">
            <evaluate expression="myService.deletePhoneNumber(userForm, requestParameters.deleteNumber)" />
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="notCorrectVerify" view="account/registerForm">

    </view-state>

    <view-state id="start">
    </view-state>


    <global-transitions>
        <transition on="changeLang">    
        </transition>
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

I also have a combo for changing the language. My question is how to achieve a change of language? How to handlechange the language ?

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <ul>
            <li class="helpLink"><a href="#">Pomoc</a></li>
            <li class="langSelect">
            <form id="langForm" action="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=changeLang" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value="${execution}" name="execution" />
                <select name="lang" id="lang" class="styled" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="pl" ${sessionScope.lang == 'pl' ? 'selected' : ''} >PL</option>
                    <option value="en" ${sessionScope.lang == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''} >EN</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

config:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl" />

    <bean id="myService" class="pl.service.MyService" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /account/register.do=flowController
                /account/verify.do=flowController    
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor"
        flow-registry="flowRegistry"></webflow:flow-executor>

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
        flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location id="verify" path="/WEB-INF/flows/verify.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
        <webflow:flow-location id="register" path="/WEB-INF/flows/register.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"
        view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" />

    <bean id="viewFactoryCreator"
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="viewResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Application Message Bundle -->

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pl" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LocaleChangeIntercepter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) will do the trick.

You have already configured it.

To read more details, have a look at the Spring Reference Chapter [15.6 Using locales](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver).

*If you want to see it in action, build a small Spring roo application, and add a second language. Then you can browse the source code add see how they (Roo) did it.*

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Spring web flow isn't the right way to handle locale-specific views.  Check out view handlers and I18N:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html